# Search between two date not return result using LINQ WPF C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datepicker

**Goal:**

Searching between two selected date by datepickers.

**Inserted dates format :**

`DateTime.Now()`

*result is:   2/23/2021 5:18:04 PM*

**Linq query :**

```
var list = from d in ctx.SellInvoices 
           where d.Date >= dtpStartDate.SelectedDate.Value 
              && d.Date <= dtpEndDate.SelectedDate.Value 
           select d;
```

**Problem :**

if *dtpEndDate* selected date is tommorow (2/24/2021) it returned result, but if i select today not returned any thing. **what is problem here?**

**Addition:**

if saved date as `DateTime.Today()` result is *2/23/2021 12:00:00 AM* and search query returned good but for *12:00:01 AM* should selecting one day later. **Here I don't want to save with DateTime.Today().**

Comment: When you take a DateTime and then use the property Date (DateTime.Now.Date>=) the date gets truncated to midnight at the beginning of the day.  To capture the entire date you need to add one day and then use Date ( < DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date

Comment: Are you using dtpEndDate.SelectedDate.Value.AddDays(1)

Comment: My DatePicker doesn't have a Selected Date so  I used : DateTime endDate =  dtpEndDate.Value.AddDays(1).Date;

Comment: I don't have a WPF project.  Is Value converting to a String()?

Comment: I used DateTime inplace ot the DateTime returned from the DatePicker.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for helping i solved it : var x = dtpPIEndDate.SelectedDate.Value  and    ```dtp = x.AddDays(1);``` and in query using dtp instead of **dtpPIEndDate**.

Answer (score 1):

If you have set dtpEndDate as just 2/23/2021 (today) it will actually be 2/23/2021 00:00:00
So when you compare d.Date <= dtpEndDate.SelectedDate.Value
It will be  2/23/2021 5:18:04 PM <= 2/23/2021 00:00:00.

Comment: You right, i know it is main problem , and i think if using AddDay(1), solved problem.